# Cannot play 2 or more audios simultaneously from Creative CA0106

Tags: sound, alsa

I have an Creative Live installed in Trusty, but this card seems not be able to play sounds from 2 sources simultaneously. ie if I'm playing music in gmusicbrowser, I cannot play an YouTube video. I must stop the player and reload the browser tab for hearing the video. Is it a card's limitation or should I configure it? (In windows it is full duplex)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Duplex" means playback and capture. Nowadays, no hardware has such mixing capabilities, and mixing is implemented by PulseAudio.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should fix the title of the answer. I need to play from 2 or more sources simultaneously, I can do it in my laptop integrated sound perfectly as it should, but I cannot with this card, its very strange.

Comment: Seems to be an config error, I reinstalled the system and now it works as should.